# Localtion of pattern for date formats in java

Tags: java, date, format, locale

In java you can get the date format based for a specific locale by doing:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en", "UK");
DateFormat format = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, locale);
System.out.println( ((SimpleDateFormat)format).toPattern());
```

This prints

```
dd-MMM-yyyy
```

Is this pattern hardcoded in a properties file somewhere? Is there any way I can extend the java mechanism and apply my own pattern (locale dependent) so when I run the above code I get:

```
dd-MM-yyyy
```

Comment: If you want a specific pattern, why don't you just specify that explicitly? Or are you trying to work with code which always asks for the medium pattern?

Comment: Yes, the idea is to work always with the same pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to work always with the same format, in my case the DateFormat.SHORT.

I end up using the short format and replacing the default format containing 2 character for the year with 4 characters for the year.

And in case someone want to know, the formats are indeed hardcoded in the package sun.text.resources under the classes FormatData_XX_YY (e.g. FormatData_en_UK).