# Java Resource Tables for Localized Date Formats

Tags: java, localization, internationalization, date-format, globalization

I already know [how to find the "short" date-format pattern Java is using for a particular locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339351/java-date-format-for-locale).  However, in C# I can go further than this; I can find [***all*** customary "short" date format patterns for a particular locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26749555/validating-locale-specific-customary-date-formats).

### Java, Pre SE 8

- Is it possible to do the same thing in Java?
- If yes, are the values returned standard to the Java platform, or are they OS specific?  In other words, could the results I receive vary based on my installation or environment?
  Java Localized Date Formats

Based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16143326/284758), I suspect the date formats (Pre SE 8) are not dependent on the OS.

### Java, Post SE 8

- Is it possible to do the same thing in Java?
- If yes, are the values returned standard to the Java platform, or are they OS specific?  In other words, could the results I receive vary based on my installation or environment?

Comment: Is there any formal definition of "all short date formats" for any locale, even the US English locale?  I mean, yes, we can think of several, but there are probably very few which are recommended by publishing style guides.  As @PawełDyda points out, the Unicode CLDR is probably the only official source.

Answer (score 0):

As they say, anything is possible for those who try. If you know how to get pattern for a single Locale, you can easily get pattern for [all supported Locales](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#getAvailableLocales()). Here is how:

```
Locale[] locales = DateFormat.getAvailableLocales();
for (Locale locale : locales) {
    DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, locale);
    if (df instanceof SimpleDateFormat) { // For the time being it will always be...
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = (SimpleDateFormat) df;
        System.out.println(sdf.toPattern());
    }
}
```

It is and probably always remain OS-independent. In Java 8 there are also other formats available, basically the ones from 
[CLDR - Unicode Common Locale Data Repository](http://cldr.unicode.org/) but it [requires quite an effort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/enhancements.8.html#cldr) to put ones hand on them.